# Correct notation of extending use case

Tags: uml, use-case, use-case-diagram

I'm wandering whether the following use case diagram is correct because I'm not sure if such notations are possible: something is going from extending use case, and this notation of this transition. I haven't found any information regarding such cases and would be glad if someone could help me.

[image]

Comment: Your use cases just don't make any sense.

Comment: Btw.: a google for "use case extend" gave me a dozen of useful answers.

Comment: @thomas-kilian , hey! On this diagram I tried to show that sportsman does not have to go to doctor if there was nothing bad - related to his health - detected; but if there was - what is an option - then he has to.

Comment: "Check if healthy" is no use case then (even worse). It's something the actors does on himself. There is no SUC. So what the heck?

Answer (score 0):

To express that a (partial or secondary) use case is used only under certain cercumstances and you want to express them explicitly, you can use extension points. An extension points defines explicitly the conditions when the Main use case is extended. In reality, this Feature of uml is Quitte rarely used. Because it adds a high degree of concreteness to the abstrakt Level of use cases.

In your example you are using the wrong kind of relation. You are showing an extend relation, which expressed that a Stereotype can be applied to a meta type. Instead you should use an extends relation, which has a dashed line and on open arrow head.

Comment: The relation currently on the diagram is a Generalization.

Comment: Denoted as extend. Typically this is draw using a Black instead of a White arrow head,but this Notation is common in some Tools.

Comment: It's more likely that is is a Generalization with name *Extends* I think